# Check all associated records before returning a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sccm, wql

So, I'm trying to create a collection in SCCM which I would like to give me a 
list of assets(`name0`) that don't have an `.ide` file linked to them that is newer than
21 days old. Once identified I can go off and investigate why these assets are not updating.

So far I have written the following query in SSMS before I set it up in SCCM,
but it's become evident that this isn't the correct approach .

```
SELECT DISTINCT v_GS_SYSTEM.Name0

FROM v_GS_SYSTEM inner join v_GS_SoftwareFile 
    ON v_GS_SoftwareFile.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID

WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, v_GS_SoftwareFile.ModifiedDate, getdate()) >=21)

       AND NOT

      (DATEDIFF(day, v_GS_SoftwareFile.ModifiedDate, getdate()) <=21)

      AND
      v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileName like '/%.ide/'

ORDER BY v_GS_SYSTEM.Name0;
```

This code returns the "correct" values but doesn't consider the fact that an asset may 
still have newer ide files related to it, which defeats the purpose of this exercise.

So (I think!) my question is, is there a way check if Name0 has any associated `ModifiedDate` records
newer than 21 days and only return a value if this check returns true/false?

EDIT: edited @MatBailie answer with output:
[image]

Comment: You want a collection of `SYSTEM.name0`, yet you also select `File.Filepath, File.FileName`?  Do you want ***all*** related files, prvided that none of them are newer than 21 days *(meaning that a system could show up multiple times)*?  Or something else?  Give example data that shows the behaviour you want, including edge cases, boundary conditions, etc.  Be specific: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hey @MatBailie , I was using `File.Filepath` & `File.FileName` for testing and forgot to remove from the question, I have now edited the question. 

To clarify, what I am after is some output that identifies unique `SYSTEM.Name0` records that have `.ide` files older than 21 days and not newer than 21 days (so I can identify machines that are not updating correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an additional `EXISTS` clause where you check this.

I believe the query you're trying to write is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vs.Name0
    , vsf.FilePath
    , vsf.FileName
FROM v_GS_SYSTEM vs
INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile vsf
    ON vsf.ResourceID = vs.ResourceID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, vsf.ModifiedDate, getdate()) >= 21)
    AND NOT (DATEDIFF(day, vsf.ModifiedDate, getdate()) <= 21) -- this seems a bit redundant and might even exclude some rows where the result is exactly (21 * 24) hours
    AND vsf.FileName LIKE '/%.ide/'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM v_GS_SoftwareFile vsf2
        WHERE vsf2.ModifiedDate > GETDATE() - 21
            AND vsf2.ResourceId = vsf.ResourceId
        )
ORDER BY vs.Name0;
```

You can basically change the check the `TRUE` / `FALSE` by keeping or removing the `NOT` in the `AND NOT EXISTS`.

**Edit:**

Since you were mentioning performance problems check if you have non-clustered idexes:

- on column `ResourceId` in v_GS_SoftwareFile table (I really hope this is not a view, but the `v_` at the start kind of makes me think this one is).
- on column `ResourceID` in v_GS_SYSTEM table (*same concerned comment here*)

Comment: I believe the date range aspect of the query is what the OP ***tried*** but didn't work as desired.  But the OP is vague enough to be largely open to interpretation.

Comment: @MatBailie You're right. I'm hoping / expecting to make changes to my answer after OP tries it.

Comment: Hey @RaduGheorghiu , I have removed the second `DATEDIFF` , you're right it is redundant. I have executed your query but It's taking a long time to run. I'll update when it's finished.

Comment: @ChristopherLong Then you might need some index tuning. Or first of all try removing the `ORDER BY`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Even after leaving your code executing over lunch it's still running (without the `ORDER BY`) So I'm not sure what's going on there!

Comment: @ChristopherLong There's nothing I can do there if I don't know row counts for each table, indexes that you have on those tables.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu they are views, is this a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170383/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-christopher-long).

Answer (score 0):

To join all `'*.ide'` Files to their Resource, but only for resources that have not had any `'*.ide'` files modified in the last 21 days...

```
SELECT
    s.Name0,
    f.FilePath,
    f.FileName
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(ModifiedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ResourceID)   AS ResourceMaxModifiedDate
    FROM
        v_GS_SoftwareFile
    WHERE
        FileName LIKE '%.ide'
)
    AS f
INNER JOIN
    v_GS_SYSTEM         AS s
        ON  s.ResourceID =  f.ResourceID
WHERE
    f.ResourceMaxModifiedDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())
ORDER BY
    s.Name0,
    f.FilePath,
    f.FileName
```

To get all Resources that have had no `'*.ide'` files modified in the last 21 days...

```
SELECT
    s.Name0
FROM
    v_GS_SYSTEM         AS s
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM v_GS_SoftwareFile    AS f
       WHERE f.FileName     LIKE '%.ide'
         AND f.ResourceID     =  s.ResourceID
         AND f.ModifiedDate  >=  DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())
    )
ORDER BY
    s.name0
```

Consider your indexes on these tables depending on which query you end up with.  A Covering index over `(ResourceID, ModifiedDate)` would be useful.  And a flag for the file type would be useful too *(`LIKE '*.ide'` is going to require scanning the rows to find the matches, it can't be solved with a typical index)*.

Comment: Ok, so I have tired both queries and both return `Name0` assets that have `ModifiedDate` values in the `v_GS_SoftwareFile` that are more recent than 21 days. I'm not too familiar with what you mean regarding a covering index, but I'll do some research, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I edited your second solution slightly to output the `FileName` / `ModifiedDate` and you can see that it's returning not only recent files, but also `.exe` extensions. perhaps that's due to my changes, I'm not sure?

Comment: Use the first solution, or the second solution. Not a hybrid of both.

Comment: ok @MatBailie , however as I mentioned I have tried both and it appeared neither worked for my circumstance. I only updated your code to check the validity of the output. If my changes have broken your original code it would be interesting to know how as I am by no means a SQL expert.

Comment: Create a minimal data set on www.sqlfiddle.com that demonstrates cases that don't work.

Comment: appears to work perfectly with test data on sqlfiddle. It looks like there may be an issue with the data in this database.